# How to compare a variable is bigger or smaller then a number with Batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to program a coding like this if you know its function

```
:check_hit

cls

if  %money% >= 5 goto  bought_hit

else

(goto need_funds)

goto check_hit
```

Please help find any errors

Comment: "Quite high" is an understatement; I've been actively coding in batch for three years and I've never needed to ask a question here because any problems I come across have already been answered here.

Comment: `if /?` should give you all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this link](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) and get inspired by this little code :

```
@echo off
set var1=20
set var2=15
set var3=2
set var4=15
IF %var1% GEQ %var2% ( echo %var1% is "bigger" than %var2% because %var1% ^> %var2%
) else (
    echo %var1% is "smaller" than %var2% because %var1% ^< %var2%
)
echo.
IF %var3% GEQ %var4% ( echo %var3% is "bigger" than %var4% because %var3% ^> %var4%
) else (
    echo %var3% is "smaller" than %var4% because %var3% ^< %var4%
)
echo.
IF %var2% GEQ %var3% ( echo %var2% is "bigger" than %var3% because %var2% ^> %var3%
) else (
    echo %var2% is "smaller" than %var3% because %var2% ^< %var3%
)
echo.
IF %var2% EQU %var4% ( echo %var2% is "equal" to %var4% because %var2% ^= %var4%)
echo.
pause
```